# how Router,Switch,Hub categories into Collision Domain and Broadcast Domain?

Tags: networking, switch, router, cisco

I always get confuse with this concept. of how many Collision domain.. and broadcast domain for Networking devices and how they work in Collision and broadcast domain . ?

Switch Hub & Router in CD and BD ?

Answer (score 2):

The Broadcast Domain is equal to or greater than the Collision Domain.

All ports on a hub are in the same collision domain (and therefore, also the same broadcast domain).

All ports on a switch are in the same broadcast domain, but separate collision domains.

Hubs connect disparate broadcast domains together.

Comment: Does anyone actually manufacture hubs any longer?  The concept of collision domains comes from early Ethernet days when many devices shared a common media, coax cable.  Also, routers connect different broadcast domains.